# Cannot show bokeh graph. How can i do?

Tags: python, bokeh

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show 

# output to static HTML file
output_file("line.html")
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

# add a circle renderer with a size, color, and alpha
p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

# show the results
show(p)
```

result is

[image]

It just has white background.
bokeh can't show it for me.
What can i do..

Comment: Are there any errors in the JS console?

Comment: at First, it well played...

Comment: But now, it don't work